# asyc/await implementation in node

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

i am trying to implement async/await in my code. But i have a doubt in that.

**Code:**

```
const a = async() => {
    var Param = { key: 'xxx' };
    const authusers = await func1(Param);
    await console.log("hello world");
}

func1() {
    dbquery {
        console.log(results);
        return results;
    }
}
```

From my understanding of async/await that is, only after first await function the second await function will be executed, then result will be like :

result

hello world

But the result is showing as:

hello world
result

Comment: await needs a Promise to wait on.

Comment: or a async method as a callee, in this case `async func1`. `async` method returns a value that is wrapped in a Promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

async/await works with Promises so you can't just return results, you need to return a Promise.

You don't need to do a wait on sync code "like console log", only on your promise function.

```js
const a = async() => {
    var Param = { key: 'xxx' };
    const authusers = await func1(Param);
    console.log(authusers)
    console.log("hello world");
}

const func1 = (param) =>{
      return new Promise(resolve =>{
        setTimeout(() =>{
          return resolve('waited')
        },1000)
      })
    
    
}
a()
```